# Self-convolution of random shape , and gauss curve

Tags: normal-distribution

I find it fascinating how all sorts of PMFs, such as the bimodal-uniform distribution below, converges to gauss curve. I was thinking, if the phenomena might go beyond probability theory, and that just about any shape (that that extends in a finite range on the x axis and is positive on the y axis) might converge to gauss curve if self-convolved enough times?

It would be hard to define a mathematical function for any random shape (that is finite range on x and positive on y), but, the act of doing convolution by letting a square pass itself on a graph and taking the overlap as the convolved function seems like it could be done "non-mathematically" too. So, I was assuming convolution by such a "visual" mechanism for the random shape.

[image]

Comment: check out the central limit theorem

Comment: I'm aware of the central limit theorem (CLT). I think it is pretty clear in the question that I was considering going outside the scope of statistics. Convolution is not by definition limited to PMFs. The CLT states that i.i.d. rv (as in, the same PMF - the same shape), when self-convolved enough times, are smoothened into a gauss curve. My question was: to what extent does this apply to more arbitrary curves (that are not necessarily PMFs or mathematically described as PMFs), and does it perhaps even apply to almost all curves. I think that was clear.

Comment: fair enough. Have you considered the Fourier transformed behavior? You will get a product, and the gaussian is controlled by the peak of the abs

Comment: I haven't considered much. I'm pretty much a beginner on the topic. It just seemed intuitively that lots of shapes should be able to (when self-convolved enough times) converge towards the gauss curve. This is mostly based on visual intuition and having seen all sorts of example curves seem to converge to it. I do not have much theory behind it, but I thought it was interesting so I asked.

Comment: please note that "any shape (that that extends in a finite range on the x axis and is positive on the y axis) "+integrable is the definition of a PMF up to normalization.

Comment: There are a few things here. 1) To many people, thinking of a shape as a shape, instead of that it has to be a PMF (even if it could), is a lot easier. It makes fewer assumptions. 2) If gauss curves appear very generally for most shapes self-convolved, it makes it a lot easier to grasp for many because it is no longer a "statistics" or "probability" thing.

Comment: I don't understand the constraints of integrable. I am thinking that shapes that are more or less impossible to mathematically describe, could still end up with the "averaged" shape of a gauss curve, and the convolution could be done visually by measuring the overlap as the shapes pass by one another. What are constraints for definition of "integrable"?